# compare two string in liferay 7.2 freemake

Tags: java, liferay-7

how to compare two string in liferay 7.2 freemaker. bellow code doesent work problem is in(<#if name=='ola'>)

```
<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
<h1>xxx</h1>
  <#if records?has_content>
     <#list records as cur_record>  
<#assign name>
${ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.renderRecordFieldValue(cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("Tekstko0o")? first, locale)}
</#assign>

    <#if name=='ola'>
    +++++ ${name} ++++++
    <#else>
    xxxx ${name} xxxxx
    </#if>

        </#list> 
    </#if>
```

Comment: Haveyou tried double quotes?

Comment: yes but still not working

Comment: *not working* means an unexpected result or an error?

Comment: unexpected result

Comment: ${name} contains "ola" and display "xxxx ola xxxxx" so instruction else is execute